# Deleting a line containing a string stored in variable not working in sed

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I am trying to delete an existing zone record from bind's named.conf file (on a CentOS 7 release).

The zone record looks like that:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "example.com.zone";
};
```

The command:

```
sed -nie '/\"example.com\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```

deletes that record (as supposed to).

Next, I have created the following shell script (rm-zone.sh) with executable permissions to do the same job:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -lt 1 ] && {
        echo "usage: $0 <domain>"
        exit 1
}

domain=$1

sed -nie '/\"$domain\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf

rndc reload

echo Zone: $domain deleted successfully
```

When I log in as root and run the command:

```
./rm-zone.sh example.com
```

I see the message "Zone example.com deleted successfully" but the zone is still in my named.conf file...

Again, when I give the above mentioned command from cli:

```
sed -nie '/\"example.com\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```

the zone is properly deleted!!!

Apparently there is something wrong in the shell script, but haven't managed to find out what it is.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, but for the variable `domain` to be expanded, it needs to be present inside double-quotes. The shell expands the variables before passing the arguments to `sed`, without the right quoting, the pattern `$domain` is interpreted as a literal string. You could nest the quotes as follows

```
sed -nie '/\"'"$domain"'\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' /etc/named.conf
```